# Connecting php 5.5 to MSSQL with dblib using Docker

Tags: php, sql-server, docker

I have a Dockerfile that gets php5.5 image, then installs a couple of extentions `(freetds-dev sendmail libpng-dev zlib1g-dev unixodbc tdsodbc nano)`. Then adds a freetds.conf and also an apache-default conf.

Then I have a docker-composer.yml that builds the dockerfile, but also takes done the `microsoft/mssql-server-linux` image.

I get down the MSSQL and I can connect it via PHPStorm, but I cannot connect to it with the PHP.

This is my connection-string:

```php
$dsn = "dblib:host=127.0.0.1:1433;dbname=table;";
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, "sa", "yourStrong(!)Password", [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
        PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES => true,
    ]);
```

It wont connect, and gives me the error

`SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)' in /var/www/html`.

I do know that the drivers to be used are installed correctly, because I can find them when using `phpinfo();`.

This is in my freetds.conf

```
[mssql]
    host = 127.0.0.1
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.0
```

This is my docker-compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    container_name: php55
    build: ./php
    links:
      - mssql
    ports:
      - "8086:80"
      - "8089:443"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html
  mssql:
    container_name: mssql
    image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
      ACCEPT_EULA: Y
      SA_PASSWORD: yourStrong(!)Password
```

What can I be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was with networking. Only using links did not work. So I created a new network with `docker network create simple-network` then added both my containers to that network. I then ran `docker inspect network simple-network` to get the IP of my MSSQL database. So I got the IP, and used that as host.

I think you can do this with networking in the docker-composer, which is probably much better.

Comment: Awesome! You should also be able to directly use `mssql` as your hostname instead of trying to find the IP. That would be more robust in the long-run.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that currently! I did add networks in the docker-compose, and now I'm connecting with the container_name. Thanks for your help, @FrankYuchengGu

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two-fold:
1. Your MSSQL container is listening on `127.0.0.1`, which is the loopback interface accessible only within the MSSQL container.
2. Your php container is attempting to connect to the database at `dblib:host=127.0.0.1:1433`. Again, this instance of the `127.0.0.1` interface is only accessible within the php container.

To fix:
1. Have your MSSQL database listen on the `0.0.0.0` address on port `1433`.
2. Change your connection string to:
`$dsn = "dblib:host=mssql:1433;dbname=table;";`. The `mssql` hostname will be resolved to the correct container IP by the Docker networking.

Since you have no network explicitly defined, docker-compose will create a default network on which both containers are attached to.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using MsSQL, but I assume the host would be the same issue anyway. I tried changing to 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1, got same error. I also checked tds version for spaces, and it looks good. So the issue is still there

Comment: Can you replace 127.0.0.1 with mssql (the name of the database container)?  Your php container looks for a database at 127.0.0.1 which is the same container. And that is why it finds nothing. You need to tell it to connect to the other container

Comment: @SebastianBerglönn sorry, there are two things that need to be changed and my original answer didn't address that. Please see my edited answer!